# Amcharts5 legend vertical align doesn't work

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts5

I am new to Amcharts5.
This is my XY chart which has 3 series:

```
var chart3 = root3.container.children.push(
  am5xy.XYChart.new(root3, {
    layout: root3.horizontalLayout
  }),
);
```

I'm trying to put a legend on the top right of my XY chart, and I followed an official doc.
This is my configuration for a vertical alignment( which is exactly the same as in the offical doc):

```
var legend = chart3.children.push(
  am5.Legend.new(root3, {
    centerY: am5.percent(0),
    y: am5.percent(0),
  })
);
```

And here is the output:
[XY Chart with Legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wBax.png)
I really don't know why it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting centerX and x also manually?

```
var legend = chart3.children.push(
  am5.Legend.new(root3, {
    centerX: am5.percent(100),
    x: am5.percent(100),
    centerY: am5.percent(0),
    y: am5.percent(0),
  })
);
```